# Cloudflare está corrompendo meus arquivos?

Tags: arquivo-zip, gzip

Galera, depois que eu estou usando serviço do cloudflare (cacheamento e proteção)
meus arquivos .zip estáticos quando clientes fazem o download, ele vem corrompido, sendo que dentro do servidor ele está normal.. alguem já passou por isso ? como resolver sem tirar o cloudflare?

Comment: tente desativar o cloudflare para ver se ele está fazendo isso, é a melhor forma, se estiver, use um subdominio sem proteção dele e coloque os arquivos lá

Comment: Edite no painel do cloudflare as extensões que você quer que ele trate ou não. Agora, pode ser um problema de mime-type no seu servidor, que só apareceu ao usar o CF. Pode ser que sem o CF, os browsers tenham deduzido o mime pela extensão, mas o CF tenha entendido outro tipo de mime. Fundamental se certificar que seu servidor manda o .zip como `application/zip`, ou ao menos `application/octet-stream`